# How to capture panel content in flex 4 - Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, capture, screen-capture, image-capture

I am creating a application in which Live video streaming in publishing in mx:video object.
I want to capture. If any one can help me out it will great for me.
else anyhow I can capture the panel content then also its fine...!!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the content as a Bitmap instance :

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(panel.width,panel.height);
bitmapData.draw(panel, new Matrix());
var bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
```

Comment: Sorry !! dude I have already tried..!! but its not working yaar.. if you find any other way please let me know.. Thanks